# How to ask for a repair shop to fix a car tire?

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales

I recently went to Panama and we had 4 flat tires within 2 weeks. I'm still confused how to properly ask for a repair shop which fixes tires. Can you clarify?

I would prefer answers not only for Panama but also for middle/south America.

There is:

- la llanta - Tire in middle america?
- la rueda - Tire everywhere else?
- el llantero - The guy/place who only fixes tires (valid everywhere?)?
- el taller (mecanico) - General repair shop?

Would

- Donde esta el proximo llantero?
- Donde se puede reparar (zurcir?) las llantas?

work?

Answer (score 4):

I use *neumático* personally (Spain Spanish) and along with *llanta* those two are the most common words.  According to the Wiki article on *neumático*, you'll also hear *cubierta*, *goma*, or *caucho* in other countries, but it does point out that *llanta* is the most common in Central America.

*Taller mecánico* to me is pretty much exclusively automotive-type repair (again, Spain Spanish), but apart from adding in farm equipment repair (or similar), I can't imagine anyone in the Spanish-speaking world not understanding what you mean with by that, especially if you've already given the context of a busted tire.  Also, from looking on-line, it seems that *taller automotriz* is used and even often in conjunction with the former as *taller de mecánica automatriz*.

*Reparar* works just fine for tires and greatly prefered over *arreglar* and a quick search found not much evidence for using *zurcir* (someone will doubtlessly point out in the comments if they've heard it)

So some possible questions that'd be pretty universally understood (again someone will point out in comments if not) would be:

- ¿Dónde está (o *queda*) el taller mecánico más cercano? (following Emilio Gort's format)
- ¿Dónde se puede reparar una llanta pinchada?
- ¿Sabe(´s/s) dónde hay un taller mecánico?  Mi llanta está pinchada.

Make sure to add in *pinchada* — that way even if *llanta* is used for something else like the rims, you'll give more than sufficient context to be understood.

Comment: And think it must be worth adding `rueda`, as is the coloquial and most common word to say in Spain over *neumático* or *llanta*, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

In some places you said:

```
Vulcanizadora
```

¿Dónde está la vulcanizadora?
Or
¿Dónde puedo reparar la llanta del auto?

All people will understand the second one.

Answer (score 2):

En Cuba nosotros llamamos a ese lugar para arreglar las gomas o llantas cuando se pinchan o ponchan:

> Ponchera

Y por lo general es entendido en todos lados, por lo menos en Colombia, Mexico y Miami me han entendido.

Podrías decir:

> ¿Dónde queda/está la ponchera más cercana?

http://hialeah.olx.com/vendo-ponchera-y-taller-de-mecanica-iid-198691856

Answer (score 2):

In northern Mexico (Specifically Chihuahua), the usual way to call tire repairing places is `desponchado` (if you [look it up in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=desponchado), most results you'll find are from Chihuahua), however `vulcanizadora` would be understood as well (but it's not very used).

Answer (score 2):

Here, in Chile, we say:

> ¿Dónde se arreglan neumáticos?

or

> ¿Dónde se arreglan ruedas?

The place is called *taller de neumáticos*.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be *very* regional.

The place is called `gomería` in Argentina, as the tires are sometimes referred to as `gomas`, a term which, by the way, can also refer to a woman's breasts, so you can call them `neumáticos` instead if you want (that is the more technical term, which you'd use to buy them online, for example)

> ¿Dónde hay una gomería?

Would be the easiest way to ask.